# Julia much slower than Java

Tags: performance, julia

I'm new to Julia and I've written a simple function that calculates RMSE (root mean square error). `ratings` is a matrix of ratings, each row is `[user, film, rating]`. There are 15 million ratings. The `rmse()` method takes 12.0 s, but Java implementation is about 188x faster: 0.064 s. Why is the Julia implementation that slow? In Java, I'm working with an array of `Rating` objects, if it was a multidimensional `int` array, it would be even faster.

```
ratings = readdlm("ratings.dat", Int32)

function predict(user, film)
    return 3.462
end

function rmse()
    total = 0.0
    for i in 1:size(ratings, 1)
        r = ratings[i,:]
        diff = predict(r[1], r[2]) - r[3]
        total += diff * diff
    end
    return sqrt(total / size(ratings)[1])
end
```

EDIT: After avoiding the global variable, it finishes in 1.99 s (31x slower than Java). After removing the `r = ratings[i,:]`, it's 0.856 s (13x slower).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Don't use globals. For annoying technical reasons, they're slow. Instead, pass `ratings` in as an argument.
- The `r = ratings[i,:]` line makes a copy, which is slow. Instead, use `predict(r[i,1], r[i,2]) - r[i,3]`.
- `square()` may be faster than `x*x` -- try it.
- If you're using the bleeding-edge Julia from source, check out the brand new [`NumericExtensions.jl` package](https://github.com/lindahua/NumericExtensions.jl), which has insanely optimized functions for many common numerical operations. ([see the julia-dev list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/julia-dev/MIooix5yi3k/discussion))
- Julia has to compile the code the first time it executes it. The right way to benchmark in Julia is to do the timing several times and ignore the first time through.

Comment: This won't affect performance, but using `size(ratings,1)` is better than `size(ratings)[1]` which creates an array object, only to then pull a single value out of it.

Comment: The fact that you're accessing a global completely sabotages code generation, which has to emit code to check the type of `ratings` and its size on every single access and dynamically chose appropriate methods for array operations, so that's definitely a huge issue here. The pointless copy of a row from ratings on each loop is also definitely an issue here. The other things probably don't matter.

Comment: After avoiding the global and the row copying, it's much faster - 13x slower than Java (down from 188x slower).

Comment: It should definitely be faster than Java. See the new note about how to benchmark in Julia. You may also want to check out the Profile package.

Comment: @Harlan I get weird results with the code in tholy's answer (see my comment there). The first timing is always slower, but only negligably.

Answer (score 7):

For me the following code runs in 0.024 seconds (and I doubt my laptop is a lot faster than your machine). I initialized ratings with the commented-out line, since I didn't have the file you referred to.

```
function predict(user, film)
    return 3.462
end

function rmse(r)
    total = 0.0
    for i = 1:size(r,1)
        diff = predict(r[i,1],r[i,2]) - r[i,3]
        total += diff * diff
    end
    return sqrt(total / size(r,1))
end

# ratings = rand(1:20, 5000000, 3)
```

Comment: It's quite weird, you're code runs in 0.05 s but if I change the number of ratings from 5_000_000 to 15_000_000, it's sometimes ~0.13s and sometimes ~0.86 s. (Every time I measure 5 times.)

Comment: Update: I get similarly inconsistent result even with 5_000_000 ratings. Sometimes 0.05, sometimes 0.26.

Comment: The inconsistent results sound like there's some sort of garbage collection going on, which is a little weird, given that your code doesn't allocate anything I don't think.

Comment: You may want to try again with a fresh build of Julia; a couple of days ago I was seeing weird garbage collection issues, but things seem back to normal again now.

Answer (score 5):

On my system the problem seems to be that your constant-valued `predict` function doesn't get optimized out. Replacing the superfluous calls to `predict` makes the code run in 0.01 seconds.

```
function time()
    ratings = ones(15_000_000, 3)
    predict(user, film) = 3.462
    function rmse(ratings)
        total = 0.0
        for i in 1:size(ratings, 1)
            diff = predict(ratings[i, 1], ratings[i, 2]) - ratings[3]
            total += diff * diff
        end
        return sqrt(total / size(ratings, 1))
    end
    rmse(ratings)
    @elapsed rmse(ratings)
end

time()

function time2()
    ratings = ones(15_000_000, 3)
    predict(user, film) = 3.462
    function rmse(ratings)
        total = 0.0
        for i in 1:size(ratings, 1)
            diff = 3.462 - ratings[3]
            total += diff * diff
        end
        return sqrt(total / size(ratings, 1))
    end
    rmse(ratings)
    @elapsed rmse(ratings)
end

time2()
```

Comment: If you pull the `predict` function out, so that it is not an inner function, then most (but not all) of the performance difference goes away.  Apparently inner functions are not inlined?