# Should I convert my R programs to Julia?

Tags: r, performance, julia

This is deliberately a quite general question but even after spending some time to read about the question it is still unclear to me in which cases I should definitely spend (a reasonable amount of) time to convert my R codes in Julia and others for which it is not worth it?

Could you provide some real-life examples for which a R-Julia conversion was helpful to improve performance (but also the readability) of your codes?

**@putters on hold of my question**: it would be very kind of you (and much helpful) to edit my question to make it suitable. Note that I asked for "real life example" in my initial question to ensure that answers are not "primarily-opinion based" ... What else could I do?

Comment: I think as a soft answer, it's worth spending time converting code to Julia if the performance you are getting from R is significantly impacting your ability to calculate what you need. Julia excels at paralleling code whereas R (by default) is single core. So if your project can easily be paralised and takes too long to run, I'd consider Julia.

Comment: It's very easy to paralellise code in R, though.

Answer (score 7):

Depends what you're going to be using the code for. In general I'd say no. I've migrated 95% of my workflow from R to Julia, but the only existing code base I've ported is my published R package (to a published julia package).
On the other hand, I ported my R analysis code to Julia halfway through this project (http://science.sciencemag.org/content/353/6307/1532) and got a 100x speedup.

Comment: That link sounds like an impressive workload where any additional speed is favourable. Was speed the main reason to migrate to Julia or do you see other key advantages? Is readability inherently better, as the question seems to imply?

Comment: I changed because I was migrating anyway, so the speed improvement was actually just an added bonus. All of the speedup was not due to running speed, a lot of it was because it was easier for me to identify optimisations of the algorithm. I personally find the code more readable, mainly because Julia passes-by-reference which makes it ideomatic to split code into smaller functions, but I guess that is also a question of taste. In my view the main advantage of julia is that it's easier for writing libraries, because multiple dispatch makes it easier to write generic code (and fast code).

Answer (score 2):

It is one question, whether or not to code primarily in Julia or in R but a whole different one, whether you want to transfer your finished R code to Julia. If you chose to write it in R primarily, it is probably because you are more proficient in R than in Julia. Thus you have quite some good chance of improving your R code or start Julia from scratch. Apparently, Julia is fast, if you know how to make it fast:  [Julia much slower than Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251805/julia-much-slower-than-java)
https://matloff.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/r-beats-python-r-beats-julia-anyone-else-wanna-challenge-r/

There has been considerable discussion about the benchmark claims of Julia, but let's assume, an average task that is slow in R was 100 times faster in Julia (and assume, your proficient enough in Julia to achieve this) and your programmers time 5 times worthier then your computer runtime (i.e. 1 hour of programming and letting the fast program run is equally an option as having one computer run 5 hours with the slower language) than we have an 20x advantage of Julia.

The question burns down to how often do you face jobs, in which this 20x advantage is really worth the effort of learning a language, keeping up with the develeopment in packages, keeping your system up to date, run the risk of loosing time because of mixing things up.

If these jobs are slow because of slow internet connection or slow hard drive, you will not realize the 20x. If you often face jobs, that are worth from speedup but are not at being parallelized, maybe C++ is even faster then Julia? If we are talking about annoyingly parallel jobs, maybe parallelization to the GPU from within R is an even faster option.

All this makes translation from running R code to Julia code worthwhile to a very special subgroup of people. I know, I have not met such a situation, but YMMV.

This is absolutely not an anti-Julia post. If you are proficient in both languages, writing your time-consuming code in Julia primarily may often be a good idea. If you are not proficient in enough in Julia for that, you may not gain as much in speed compared to investing your time into R optimization as you may think.

Comment: Your analysis is useful if you view the translation purely in terms of runtime speedup. There may be other reasons to migrate, though, such as whether it can make the code more flexible, readable and maintaintainable.

Comment: The question was mostly about performance but also readability. Being a compiled language, Julia is inherently faster than R and faster is better. I do not know, whether Julia inherently improves readability but I do not see problems with readability in well written R. To some large extend, that is subjective. Concerning long term maintainability, I see a distinct disadvantage in Julia being in version 0.6 and not 1.0. (to be ctd.)

Comment: (cont.) Julia is not mainstream, it is very young. Both no problems for use-once code, but even if Julia is remarkably stable for such a young language, if maintainability is key, use something old and proven (think: basic R, not: the Hadleyverse).

Comment: I'm not well acquainted with R, but my experience with natively slow (relying on fast external libraries) languages is that one must often 'massage' and sometimes contort the algorithms into barely readable vectorized form. Multiple dispatch removes the need for extensive input checking boilerplate, yielding brief, simple functions, without needing 'clever' tricks for speed. Readability is certainly a strong point in favour of Julia.

Comment: "There has been considerable discussion about the benchmark claims of Julia" where has there been a credible discussion on this where the author disputing the claim hasn't been completely wrong? That would be a new one... "maybe C++ is even faster then Julia?" Why would that be true given the dispatch + lowering mechanism Julia uses? Could you describe a piece of the compiler architecture that backs that actually backs that up, or is this just FUD? "your programmers time 5 times worthier then your computer runtime" Why would Julia be slower (instead of faster) to write? You don't have to vec

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I do not take any position on all of these benchmark claims -- obviously the matter of how to measure these things is very complicated and different people have different results. If you can tell, that all these authors are completely wrong: good for you. Still true, that there has been a discussion. "Why would Julia be slower (instead of faster) to write?" Please read my post: I claimed, that writing again, what has already been written, takes additional time. Nothing more. First sentence.

Comment: You claimed more than that. You show that you are skeptical of the benchmarks. Skepticism of established results is a stance. "there has been a discussion" is not an argument to be skeptical. Your "I will not take a position because there's a discussion" position is the exact same setup that climate denialists use to dodge responsibility. So please tell me, what about the architecture of Julia's compilation process leads you to be skeptical that it will actually hit C++ speeds on type-stable code? If you don't have an reason for your claims then you are spreading FUD.

Comment: "Please read my post: I claimed, that writing again, what has already been written, takes additional time. Nothing more." No, you did claim more, and it's the more that you claimed that is an issue. If you didn't say more than this I would agree with you.

Comment: After many years, migrating the code partially is an other option using the RCall package. Julia and R objects can be passed from both languages to other by automatic conversation.